# Create mesh from Bounding box / Render bounding box

Tags: blender, mesh, bounding-box

I need to create a mesh from the bounding box of an animated object.

Is there any way to do this in blender 2.8?

Comment: For [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/14188/935) I created an addon that creates a cube matching the bounding box of all selected objects. Also you can set the [display type](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/scene_layout/object/properties/display.html) of an object to bounding box.

Comment: thank you, it worked. But is it possible to get an animated bounding box from an animated object?

Comment: While you could create one for each frame, I would wonder what your end goal is? A function could give you the bound box for any frame. For a visual animated box I would look at using [app.handlers](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html) to update the size every frame. If you ask at [BSE](https://blender.stackexchange.com) with some more details, someone should offer a solution.